# Swift Error when Returning from Portrait to Landscape mode

Tags: swift, homekit

My application has just set the Landscape Mode. I use The Table View only for add the accessory in my home.

[image]

My problem is that when I add a new accessory, my application comes into portrait mode to open the settings window code

[image]

for to pair the accessory, after having carried out the assignment successfully , The Table View returns the first black Window but staying in Portrait mode. I tried to stabilize this in AppDelegate through

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {


    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == true){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    if (shouldSupportAllOrientation == false){
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape

    }}
```

and in my TableViewController

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, HMAccessoryBrowserDelegate {

let homeManager = HMHomeManager()
let browser = HMAccessoryBrowser()
let appdelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var accessories = [HMAccessory]()


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  let accessory = accessories[indexPath.row] as HMAccessory

    if let home = homeManager.primaryHome {

        for room in home.rooms {

            if room.name == “Kitchen” {

                self.appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = true

                homeManager.primaryHome?.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in

                 if error != nil {

                        print("ERROR 1 \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                      }
                    else {

                        self.homeManager.primaryHome?.assignAccessory(accessory, toRoom: room, completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in

                            if error != nil {

                                print("ERROR 2 \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                            } else {
                                print("Accessory Add successfully")
                                self.appdelegate.shouldSupportAllOrientation = false
                                self.performSegueWithIdentifier(“goToBlackView”, sender: self)

                            }})}})}}}

}}
```

But when the Black view back it seems that my device is locked in Portrait Mode, but after a few seconds as soon as I make a mini shake the phone, the black view back in landascape mode. how can I overcome this problem?

EDIT :

I have set my storyboard in this mode

[image]

but i have this error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [HMSetupViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Comment: Are you setting it only in appDelegate? Had you do that in info.plist too?

Comment: yes in my info.plist is ok